# C++ Do I Understand Polymorphism Correctly?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, derived-class, overriding

Bar and Box are derived classes of Foo and Foo has a virtual function F() and Bar and Box both have function F(). From what I understand, polymorphism correctly allows Bar.F() instead of Box.F() or Box.F() instead of Bar.F() to override Foo.F() using some runtime routine without knowing whether your object is a Bar or a Box. It's something like this:

`Foo * boxxy = new Box;

boxxy->F();`

The last line will call the right F() (in this case, Box.F()) independent of whether boxxy is a Box or a Bar or a Foo (in which case the implementation of the virtual Foo.F() is called).

Do I understand this right? And what changes if boxxy is a Box pointer? And what happens if the derived class doesn't have an override for F()? Lastly, to avoid implementing a function for a base class but still allow polymorphism, do you just write an empty function body and declare it virtual? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly right - consider this inheritance tree:

```
      Foo
     /   \
   Bar   Box
```

If you now make a pointer like this:

```
Bar* barry = new Box();
```

You'll get a [nice compiler error](http://ideone.com/4DQzi), since a `Box` can't be converted to a `Bar`. :)
So it's only `Foo<->Bar` and `Foo<->Box`, never `Bar<->Box`.
Next, when `boxxy` is a `Box` pointer, it will only ever call the `Box::F` function, if it is provided.
And last, to force subclasses to implement a certain function, you declare it `pure virtual`, like this:

```
virtual void Func() = 0;
//   note this --- ^^^^
```

Now subclasses (in this case `Bar` and `Box`), **must** implement `Func`, else they will fail to compile.

Comment: Thanks so much. Just out of curiosity, you can use NULL in lieu of 0 right?

Comment: @Brandon: No, not when declaring a pure virtual function. The exakt token that is needed is `=0`, nothing else. Also, I'd encourage you to use `0` instead of `NULL` and when C++0x comes, use `nullptr` for pointer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the right F() will be called dependent on the type of object you have created through your Foo pointer.

If boxxy were a Box pointer you could only call it's F() or one of it's derived class's F(), unless you did a dynamic_cast to it's parent class and then called F().

To avoid having to implement in the base class you define it as *pure virtual* like so:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    virtual void F() = 0; //notice the = 0, makes this function pure virtual.

};
```

Answer (score 1):

> And what changes if boxxy is a Box
>   pointer?

It will allow access to the methods of Box not inherited from Foo. Box pointer can't point to Bar objects, since Bar isn't derived from Box.

> And what happens if the derived class
>   doesn't have an override for F()?

It will inherit the implementation of F() from the base class.

> Lastly, to avoid implementing a
>   function for a base class but still
>   allow polymorphism, do you just write
>   an empty function body and declare it
>   virtual?

It will work, but it is not a right way to do polymorphism. If you can't come up with a concrete implementation for the virtual function of the base class make that function pure virtual, don't implement it as empty function.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare Foo like this

```
class Foo
{
private:
  Foo() {};
public:
  void func() const { std::cout << "Calling Foo::func()" << std::endl; }
};
```

and Bar like this

```
class Bar : public Foo
{
private:
  Bar() {};
public:
  void func() const { std::cout << "Calling Bar::func()" << std::endl; }
};
```

then

```
Foo* bar = new Bar();
bar->func();
```

will call Foo::func().

If you declare Foo like this

```
class Foo
{
private:
  Foo() {};
public:
  virtual void func() const { std::cout << "Calling Foo::func()" << std::endl; } // NOTICE THE virtual KEYWORD
};
```

then

```
Foo* bar = new Bar();
bar->func();
```

will call Bar::func().

Answer (score 0):

- Do I understand this right? Yes, if the function was declared as a virtual function.
- And what changes if boxxy is a Box
  pointer? Depends on whether the
  function is virtual or not. A virtual
  function will always end up calling
  the proper derived function; a
  non-virtual function will call the
  version based on the type of the
  pointer.
- And what happens if the derived class
  doesn't have an override for F()? It
  will use the base class definition.
- Lastly, to avoid implementing a
  function for a base class but still
  allow polymorphism, do you just write
  an empty function body and declare it
  virtual? You can also declare it pure
  virtual: `virtual void F() = 0`. Any
  class that intends to be instantiated
  into an object much override this
  function and give it a proper
  implementation.